# When is the operator associated to a sesquilinear form normal?

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, self-adjoint-operators

I am self-studying from *Linear Algebra* by Hoffman and Kunze. In chapter 9, it is stated that every sesqui-linear form $f$ on a finite-dimensional inner product space $(V,(\cdot|\cdot))$ can be associated to a unique operator $T: V \to V$ such that
$$f(\alpha,\beta) = (T\alpha|\beta), \quad \forall \alpha,\beta \in V.$$
It is then shown that $f$ is Hermitian if and only if $T$ is self-adjoint. I would like to know if there is there some property $\mathcal{P}$ of sesqui-linear forms such that $f$ satisfies $\mathcal{P}$ if and only if $T$ is normal.

I apologize if this is a trivial question, and I thank all of you in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid there is no such noteworthy property, otherwise it would have been already named. Nonetheless, let's recall that a normal operator satisfies the condition $T^\dagger T = TT^\dagger$, which can be reformulated as $(T\alpha,T\beta) = (T^\dagger\alpha,T^\dagger\beta)$. From there, it may be translated as
$$
f(\alpha,T\beta) 
   = (T\alpha,T\beta)
   = (T^\dagger\alpha,T^\dagger\beta) 
   = (T^\dagger\beta,T^\dagger\alpha)^*
   = (T\beta,T\alpha)^*
   = f(\beta,T\alpha)^*,
$$
which can be seen as an analog of the hermitian property (with an extra $T$).

Comment: I understand. Thank you.